# I am almost there but program can not recognize negatives

Tags: python-3.x

Program has to count positive and negative numbers and compute the average. I feel like i have the right code but maybe something is off. This was done on python idle 3.5. I would appreciate any and all help.

```
#Variables
total=0
pos=0
neg=0
avg=0
i=eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:"))

#main
while (i!=0):
    total=total+i
    i=eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:"))

    if(i>0):
        pos+=1

    elif(i<0):
        neg+=1


print("The number of positives is ", pos)
print("The number of negatives is ", neg)
print("The total is",total)
print("The average is ", avg)


avg=total/(pos+neg)
```

Comment: What do you mean "_maybe_ something is off"? Does the program produce the desired output?

Comment: `eval(input())`? Live fast, die young?

Comment: For safety replace `eval()` with `int()`

Answer (score 1):

One Problem your code has is, that the first number you are entering does not count towards either the positive or negative counts in your loop because it is outside of it. As soon as you enter the loop you do add it to the total, but then you ask for the next number. This way your first number is never evaluated.

What you could do is a while loop that has the condition "True", so it runs every time you start the program. The evaluation on whether your input is a zero can be (and in this case must be) handled in your else/elif/else block.
If you don't include a break there you are getting an infinite loop.

You should not us eval(). The Documentation on python states this:

> This function can also be used to execute arbitrary code objects (such as those created by compile()). In this case pass a code object instead of a string. If the code object has been compiled with 'exec' as the mode argument, eval()’s return value will be None.

If you use int() the program knows if it is negative or not since you compare the input to zero in your if statements.

Maybe do something like this:

```
#Variables
total = 0
pos = 0
neg = 0
# avg = 0 (you don't have to declare this variable since you calculate it
# anyway later on)

# removed the input from here since it did not contribute to the pos/neg count

#main
while (True):
    # maybe use a while loop with the condition "True" so it runs every time

    i = int(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: "))

    total = total + i

    if(i > 0):
        # counts 1 up if integer is positive
        pos += 1

    elif(i < 0):
        # counts 1 up if integer is negative
        neg += 1

    else:
        # break out of the loop as soon as none of the above conditions is true
        # (since it hits a 0 as input)
        # else you get an infinite loop
        break

avg = total / (pos + neg)

print("The number of positives is ", pos)
print("The number of negatives is ", neg)
print("The total is ", total)
print("The average is ", avg)
```